Animation image and text
My code contains an img and text will popup if the img is clicked.
I want to make the second image and third image (on bottom) be animated when the text pops up (when the first image is clicked). It should move down smoothly and also with the text when the text popup so the text also smoothly popup. Any clues on how to do that?


document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.getElementById("text").style.display === "none") {
    document.getElementById("text").style.display = "block"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").style.display = "none"
  }
})
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
<div id="image">This is image</div>
<p id="text">some text about image context. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora repudiandae nisi aut quos. Voluptas libero dolore laboriosam ipsum officia, debitis provident corporis quis. Quia, earum quos. Accusantium ipsam dignissimos
  officia? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima saepe quidem veniam voluptatem rem delectus voluptates earum maiores, error laudantium ipsum neque exercitationem expedita perferendis eveniet, asperiores tempore consectetur iste?
</p>

<div>second image</div>
<p>some text about image context</p>
<div>thrid image</div>




Yes instead of toggling the display you should be toggling the height with a transition. The downside is you need to define the height (or max-height) of the text.
Also, you should be toggling a class rather then changing the style directly.


document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("text").classList.toggle("shown")
})
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
}

#text {
  height: 0px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: 500ms;
}

#text.shown {
  height: 300px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="image">This is image</div>
  <p id="text">some text about image context. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora repudiandae nisi aut quos. Voluptas libero dolore laboriosam ipsum officia, debitis provident corporis quis. Quia, earum quos. Accusantium ipsam dignissimos
    officia? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima saepe quidem veniam voluptatem rem delectus voluptates earum maiores, error laudantium ipsum neque exercitationem expedita perferendis eveniet, asperiores tempore consectetur
    iste?
  </p>

  <div>second image</div>
  <p>some text about image context</p>
  <div>thrid image</div>

</body>

</html>



